# How to find the index of closing brace after a particular string

Tags: java, string, matching

I need to find the first closing brace `"}"` after I find a particular string. The string is 
as below :

> ..........."message": "RM06050" }]

I need to first find "**RM06050**" , then find the first closing brace and add a string there, for e.g in above string I want to add **"This is added string" after "}" but before "]"**. The blank characters between the string and braces may vary ...

Comment: Search for the string, get the index, search for braces after that index. We're not here to write your code.

Comment: Please tell if RM06050 is always coming? Can you provide exact format of message? like what is befor "message".

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: To me it looks like JSON - if that's the case you could use a JSON-library for java to manipulate the contents.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
int i = s.indexOf('}', s.indexOf("\"RM06050\""));
```